# Rails 4.1 ActiveRecord::relation is no more like Array

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

in Rails 4.0.4 this code work:

```
mailboxes = Mailbox.order(:mailbox)
mailboxes.keep_if do |mailbox|
  # test
end
```

in Rails 4.1.0 it break with `NoMethodError (undefined method keep_if for <Mailbox::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x5494f80>)`

and has to be changed to

```
mailboxes = Mailbox.order(:mailbox).to_a
mailboxes.keep_if do |mailbox|
  # test
end
```

I don't find any information about that

Any idea?

Answer (score 40):

Its in [release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes) for rails 4.1

> Relation no longer has mutator methods like #map! and #delete_if.
>   Convert to an Array by calling #to_a before using these methods. (Pull
>   Request)

Since `keep_if` is a mutator method, its removed from `Relation`

Comment: This explains why I couldn't get a proper JSON response on my 'respond_with User.all'. But doing a respond_with User.all.to_a properly invoked my to_json method, and gave me the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: solved my error after a `Modal.order` call: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'sort_by!' for #<Modal::ActiveRecord_Relation>`